# Register VS2008 Professional on Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7, installation, license-key

I received from Microsoft a free copy of VS2008 Professional, which is cool.  But when I went to install on Windows 7 Beta, it installs fine, but is marked as being "unregistered".  I have my license key, but cannot get to where I can enter the key.

The deal was I had to DL the trial version and then do an upgrade.  I was able to do this on Vista because I already had VS2008 Team installed and then just "switched" to the Professional version.

But on Windows 7 (may just be due to clean install), I cannot get the prompt to allow me to enter the serial number.   When you install the trial, you only get a hardcoded trial serial number pre-entered.

The suggestion to use Programs and Features to amend the installation doesn't work as it does not give me the "upgrade / enter serial #" option as described.

Anyone else solve this?

I know I'm 89 days away, but I hate leaving this issues outstanding. :)

TIA!

**EDIT: This is NOT a software piracy question, but a valid legitimate issue.  This works in Windows Vista, but not on Windows 7 -- so I'm hoping someone here has solved this issue.  Thanks.**

***UPDATE:  Wrote the PR Firm who was handling this for Microsoft and they are shipping me out the DVD later this week.  Still this might prove valuable for someone else.***

Comment: Not programming related and smells like software piracy. If it's legit, you have Microsoft to support you. This is not the place.

Comment: And your answer "smells" like plagiarism, though I'm sure it's not.  Sorry, but this is a legit and valid question.

Comment: Besides, if I were "Stealing" the software, wouldn't I take the full fledged version and not the basic Pro model?

Comment: I'd insert what Yuval A said, but that would be plagiarism.  Vote to close.

Comment: Actually, I knew completely what I said when I compared your answer to plagiarism.  It is as close to plagiarism as my question was to piracy.   I added the NPR tag because of your whine.  The only good thing to come from your post.  Try being cooperative instead of hostile.

Comment: From the FAQ: Be nice.
Treat others with the same respect you'd want them to treat you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still no solution here -- it's busted in Windows 7 it would appear.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: FYI, having the DVD didn't work either.  There is a known issue with upgrading to SP1 prior to registering.

Answer (score 1):

Although not the "best" way to do it.  I strongly recommend just uninstalling and reinstalling VS.

I have had so many issues going from Trial to full that I haven't even bothered trying recenty due to issues like this.

It may be a bit painful at first, but realistically it will be better than one day going to start VS and having it not come up due to an invalid license key.

Comment: Problem is, this is how I received it from Microsoft.  All I have is the .ISO for the trial version and the license key (this is legit, BTW).  It was a "Wow VS2008 is great" webinar and all the attendees got this.

Comment: Dang!  That sucks! 

WHen you installed the trial, was there any way to provide the key?  it might just be a windows 7 "issue" or feature.

Comment: No, when you install, it's prefilled with the serial # for the trial.  But exactly what I want to do is supposed to be doable by simply going to the Programs and Features, but it's not working.  Scott Guthrie covered what should work at http://tinyurl.com/bzrfbw

Comment: Yup, looks like you found a nice little Windows 7 Bug!

Glad to hear that you have a new disk coming!

Answer (score -1):

Just tested this for Vista Ultimate with the VS2008 Trial:

1. Go to Control Panel -> Programs & Features
2. Find "Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition - ENU"
3. Click "Uninstall/Change"
4. Once it has finished checking resources and loading Config click Next
5. You should be presented with four options, the fourth option is "Upgrade to Microsoft Visual Studio 2008"

Hope that Helps

Comment: Sorry no... this is exactly what I said was NOT working when it should.